# Is it possible to merge cells with an openpyxl write-only worksheet?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am creating worksheets with about 100,000 rows and openpyxl's writing operation is quite slow. It would be useful to get a row object and to fill it in, but I can't find an API for that. The [documentation on optimization](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html) mentions write-only mode. My problem with this mode is that it doesn't obviously support merged cells, because merging cells seems to be an operation that is done on a spreadsheet, not on a row that is appended.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell import WriteOnlyCell
from openpyxl.comments import Comment
from openpyxl.styles import Font
wb = Workbook(write_only = True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()
cell = WriteOnlyCell(ws, value="hello world")
cell.font = Font(name='Courier', size=36)
cell.comment = Comment(text="A comment", author="Author's Name")
ws.append([cell, 3.14, "foo","bar",None])
ws.append(["merged cells"])
ws.merge_cells(start_row=2,end_row=2,start_column=1,end_column=5)
wb.save('write_only_file.xlsx')
```

```
% python cm.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cm.py", line 12, in <module>
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=2,end_row=2,start_column=1,end_column=5)
AttributeError: 'WriteOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'merge_cells'
```

Is there any way to support merging cells? Failing that, what's a faster way to write cells than to get each cell with `ws.cell()` and manually set it?

Comment: Merged cells is, at least in my opinion, not done! It creates problems later on for sure. That being said, if you using xlwings instead of openpyxl and check it's API property, you'll be able to interact with excel much cleaner using arrays to fill a range object of cells in one go.

Comment: You can replace `.merge_cells` with `.merged_cells.add(cell_range)`. **Note**: The whole `merge` stuff is version dependant, tested with `3.03` on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SlategrayWoefulMicroscope)

Comment: @stovfl — What is `cell_range`?

Comment: @JvdV — Thanks, I was not aware of xlwings. I'll check it out.

Comment: @vy32 ***"What is cell_range?"***: See the given link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messing around with the `merged_cells` attribute of the worksheet worked for me. Here is an example:

```py
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet("Test")

ws.append(['A', '', '', '', '', 'B', '', '', '', ''])

for _ in range(100):
    ws.append(['%d' % i for i in range(10)])

ws.merged_cells.ranges.add("A1:E1")
ws.merged_cells.ranges.add("F1:J1")

wb.save("Test.xlsx")
```

Comment: Great going! Thanks.

Comment: Note that this manipulates the collection of merged cells directly which also means that if, for example, you want borders on the merged cells, you'll have to work out how to do this yourself.

Comment: As of version 3.1.2 (possibly earlier) the collection of merged cell ranges has become a set, so `append` needs updating to `add`: `ws.merged_cells.ranges.add("A1:E1")`

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible in write-only mode to specify if cells are merged.

The information regarding merged cells is at the **end** of the worksheet and the API currently doesn't support this functionality, although it would probably be possible to add the code to do this.

Comment: I don't want to determine *whether* cells are merged, I want to *merge cells* written in write-only mode. Although it seems that If I get a range iterator I can improve performance enough that I don't need to use write-only mode.

Comment: You still can't do this because of the way `ws.merge_cells()` works though it would probably be possible to add the code to do this.

Comment: See @mavroprovato post, it is now possible.